# Unexpected behaviour from `specs` in `plotly.subplots.make_subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graph, plotly

From the relevant `plotly` tutorial [page](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/), we have the following example:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{}, {}],
           [{"colspan": 2}, None]],
    subplot_titles=("First Subplot","Second Subplot", "Third Subplot"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 1, 2]),
                 row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, title_text="Specs with Subplot Title")
fig.show()
```

which generates the following graph:

[image]

I am trying to place `Third Subplot` in the top row and `First Subplot` and `Second Subplot` in the second row. I am using the following code (identical with the preceding piece, with only the `specs` option altered appropriately):

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"colspan": 2}, None],
           [{}, {}]],
    subplot_titles=("First Subplot","Second Subplot", "Third Subplot"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
                 row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 1, 2]),
                 row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, title_text="Specs with Subplot Title")
fig.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-cab6bb97a5c7> in <module>
     11 
     12 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2], y=[1, 2]),
---> 13                  row=1, col=2)
     14 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[2, 1, 2]),
     15                  row=2, col=1)

~/path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1613             rows=[row] if row is not None else None,
   1614             cols=[col] if col is not None else None,
-> 1615             secondary_ys=[secondary_y] if secondary_y is not None else None,
   1616         )
   1617 

~/path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols, secondary_ys)
   1711         if rows is not None:
   1712             for trace, row, col, secondary_y in zip(data, rows, cols, secondary_ys):
-> 1713                 self._set_trace_grid_position(trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1714 
   1715         # Make deep copy of trace data (Optimize later if needed)

~/path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in _set_trace_grid_position(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y)
   1792         grid_ref = self._validate_get_grid_ref()
   1793         return _set_trace_grid_reference(
-> 1794             trace, self.layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y
   1795         )
   1796 

~/path/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/subplots.py in _set_trace_grid_reference(trace, layout, grid_ref, row, col, secondary_y)
   1317             """
   1318 No subplot specified at grid position ({row}, {col})""".format(
-> 1319                 row=row, col=col
   1320             )
   1321         )

ValueError: 
No subplot specified at grid position (1, 2)
```

I have tried different options for `specs` and they have worked, but this one I am not able to make work. Am I providing the arguments in the wrong fashion or might this be a known issue with `plotly`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `No subplot specified at grid position (1, 2)` seems correct to me: you now have a single 2-column plot in the first row, but you're trying to add a trace to `row=1, col=2`... You probably want to change this line to target `row=2, col=2` given that you've swapped the rows in the original spec.

Comment: How did I miss that! Thank you, Nicolas!